# Trying to get Django to load the server without using the paths I created. The default path is not working

Tags: django, django-urls

my urls.py will not allow Django to run the server.

The error message visual studio code gives when I hover over the red squiggly line that visual studio gives over the URL patterns [ is: "[" was not closed.

Can anyone explain to me what that error message means and how to solve it?

Also, I am trying to get my Django server to run the server on its own. But it will not open the main page. It was able to run the other paths when I put the URL after the /'finance' or /'ingredients' respectively but that was before the bug popped up. I am certain the error is tied to preventing Django to load the server.

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.http import HttpResponse

urlpatterns = [ # <----- error is on this thing
    path('admin/',name ='inventory' admin.site.urls),
    path('finance/', finance, name='finance'),
    path('home/', home, name='home'), #I am attempting to connect the home_view function with the views function.
    path('ingredients/', ingredients, name='ingredients'),
    path('menu/', menu, name='menu'),
    path('purchases/', purchases, name='purchases'),]
```

views.py

```
def finance(request):
    return HttpResponse('Here are our business results')

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse

def ingredients(request):
    return HttpResponse('Here is the ingredients page')

def menu(request):
    return HttpResponse('Here is the menu page!')

def purchases(request):
    return HttpResponse('Here is where you can find the order history!')
```

[image]

What have I tried to do to solve the problem?
I have tried looking at stack overflow examples.
I have tried reaching out on the Django discord.
I have tried researching the error message on the internet.
I have tried looking at a Django course on an udemy equivalent.

Comment: It means that you have a `[` without a matching `]`. The easiest way to avoid this is to indent all of the lines that you think are inside the `[]` and put the closing `]` on a separate line at the end, but at the same indentation level as the `urlpatterns...` line. If you don't have the `]` at the end, it will be immediately obvious when you consistently use this style of formatting.

Comment: I copied your code into VS Code and don't get any errors. Will you [edit] your question to show a screenshot of the error you see?

Comment: Also, what happens when you open a terminal and type `python manage.py runserver`? Do you get any errors?

Comment: it turns out the [] needed to not have as much white space. when I changed the indentation that part of it worked. as for python manage.py run server it is not finding the default page for the server but it is finding the other pages on the server when I type in what comes after the /

Comment: White space will only cause an error if it is incorrect when declaring classes, functions, if statements, for loops, and while loops. It doesn't cause errors when declaring a list as you are here.

Comment: As for the "page not found" error, this is because you have not defined a view for the default route.

Comment: so I need to make a path('') that is not built in when I create the file. you would think Django would make a default path when I created the app with the startup command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you already fixed the issue with unclosed `[]`.

It seems that the path for the root "/" is missing in the urls declaration.
You need to explicitly tell django which view you want to run in that path.
Look this example:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        '',
        TemplateView.as_view(template_name='template/index.html'),
        name='index',
    ),
]
```

Comment: in the declaration? do you mean when I type out the url?

Comment: @strikeouts27 Yes, he means in the `urlpatterns` list.

Comment: @yaderv when I import TemplateView and run the code it says the following error message: TemplateDoesNotExist at /
template/index.html?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice can you give me an example for a default path please?

Comment: what should the default page look like? a login page or the rocket ship taking off because I have the login page?

Comment: what should the default page look like? a login page or the rocket ship taking off because I have the login page? I just realized that, the default page should be the page I want most users to arrive at. So having it show the rocket ship logo base page is not necessary. I feel so silly! But at the very least I understand that to change the default path I need to set it to the path(''). thank you to everyone who helped and attempted to help!

Comment: @strikeouts27  `TemplateView` is the view, and it is imported this way `from django.views.generic import TemplateView`. In this case I'm using a generic view, but you can use you custom ones. Please see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/class-based-views/

About what should be in the index ("/"), well that depends on you or the project needs.